# How to log only iptables messages into my /var/log/iptables.log?

Tags: iptables, logs, rsyslog

I want to log only iptables message into  `/var/log/iptables.log`.
Here is my way.

```
sudo vim /etc/rsyslog.conf
kern.*      -/var/log/iptables.log
sudo vim  /etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.conf
:msg, startswith, "NETFILTER" -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 10/m -j LOG  --log-prefix NETFILTER
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
sudo systemctl restart  rsyslog
```

And to clear all log messages in /var/log/iptables.log.

```
sudo echo "" |sudo tee /var/log/iptables.log
```

Now to reboot  pc.

```
sudo cat  /var/log/iptables.log
Nov 19 09:21:29 MiWiFi kernel: [    7.069752] input: Eee PC WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input15
Nov 19 09:21:29 MiWiFi kernel: [    7.069918] asus_wmi: Number of fans: 1
Nov 19 09:21:29 MiWiFi kernel: [    7.264095] Adding 1952764k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1952764k FS
Nov 19 09:21:29 MiWiFi kernel: [   11.464093] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Nov 19 09:21:31 MiWiFi kernel: [   13.153842] Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
Nov 19 09:21:31 MiWiFi kernel: [   13.529229] r8169 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw (-2)
Nov 19 09:21:31 MiWiFi kernel: [   13.529300] r8169 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw failed with error -2
Nov 19 09:21:31 MiWiFi kernel: [   13.529307] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: unable to load firmware patch rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw (-2)
Nov 19 09:21:31 MiWiFi kernel: [   13.542639] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Nov 19 09:21:31 MiWiFi kernel: [   13.542657] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Nov 19 09:21:31 MiWiFi kernel: [   13.542749] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
Nov 19 09:21:33 MiWiFi kernel: [   15.517613] NET: Registered protocol family 4
Nov 19 09:21:33 MiWiFi kernel: [   15.543358] NET: Registered protocol family 3
Nov 19 09:21:33 MiWiFi kernel: [   15.573343] NET: Registered protocol family 5
Nov 19 09:21:34 MiWiFi kernel: [   16.105505] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
Nov 19 09:21:34 MiWiFi kernel: [   16.105513] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
Nov 19 09:21:36 MiWiFi kernel: [   18.128165] NETFILTERIN= OUT=enp3s0 SRC=192.168.31.52 DST=224.0.0.22 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 MARK=0xd4 
Nov 19 09:21:36 MiWiFi kernel: [   18.173678] NETFILTERIN= OUT=enp3s0 SRC=192.168.31.52 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=236 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=65025 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=216 
Nov 19 09:21:36 MiWiFi kernel: [   18.424244] NETFILTERIN= OUT=enp3s0 SRC=192.168.31.52 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=236 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=65028 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=216 
Nov 19 09:21:36 MiWiFi kernel: [   18.674976] NETFILTERIN= OUT=enp3s0 SRC=192.168.31.52 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=236 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=65082 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=216 
Nov 19 09:21:36 MiWiFi kernel: [   18.812203] NETFILTERIN= OUT=enp3s0 SRC=192.168.31.52 DST=224.0.0.22 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 MARK=0xd4 
Nov 19 09:21:42 MiWiFi kernel: [   24.142666] fuse init (API version 7.26)
Nov 19 09:21:56 MiWiFi kernel: [   38.904380] NETFILTERIN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2471 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59188 DPT=4101 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Part 1 is the info on kernel start for my pc such as following.

```
Nov 19 09:21:29 MiWiFi kernel: [    7.069752] input: Eee PC WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input15
Nov 19 09:21:29 MiWiFi kernel: [    7.069918] asus_wmi: Number of fans: 1
Nov 19 09:21:29 MiWiFi kernel: [    7.264095] Adding 1952764k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1952764k FS
Nov 19 09:21:29 MiWiFi kernel: [   11.464093] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Nov 19 09:21:31 MiWiFi kernel: [   13.153842] Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
```

Part 2 is the info on iptables messages for my pc such as following.

```
Nov 19 09:21:36 MiWiFi kernel: [   18.812203] NETFILTERIN= OUT=enp3s0 SRC=192.168.31.52 DST=224.0.0.22 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 MARK=0xd4 
Nov 19 09:21:56 MiWiFi kernel: [   38.904380] NETFILTERIN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2471 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59188 DPT=4101 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

How to log only iptables messages (part 2 instead of part 1) into my /var/log/iptables.log ,not contains both kernel info and iptables info in /var/log/iptables.log ?

Comment: You need to remove the line `kern.*      -/var/log/iptables.log` if you dont want all kernel messages in that log file.

Comment: if you remove  `kern.* -/var/log/iptables.log` ,both part1 and part2 will not be written into iptables.log.

Comment: Stop rsyslog and run it by hand with debug: `sudo rsyslogd -dn`

Answer (score 2):

In your rsyslog.conf example, you send both
`kern.*` AND `:msg, startswith, "NETFILTER"` to iptables.log, where `kern.*` already includes the iptables messages.

In your example, correct the kern.* destination in rsyslog.conf to the default kern.log file:

```
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
```

Place this the /etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.conf and reload/restart rsyslog:

```
:msg, regex, "NETFILTER" -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
```

Note the 'regex' instead of 'startswith'. Refine the regex string if this works.

Please accept any of the answers you were given to close the question.